# How to import an object in typescript without tripping intellisense?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, durandal, durandal-2.0

I am using typescript with durandal as a proof of concept and honestly they aren't gelling.

Most recently I'm trying to troubleshoot the following intellisense error:

"Cannot convert typeof calendarServiceImport to ICalendarService"

```
///<reference path="service/CalendarService.ts"/>
import calendarServiceImport = require("service/CalendarService");

var calendarService: ICalendarService;
calendarService = calendarServiceImport;
```

With Durandal, the import call is supposed to be a DI call and should be an instance, but typescript parser is thinking it should be a type instead.

Here's the code I'm trying to import:

```
/// <reference path="../contracts/ICalendarService.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../../configure.d.ts"/>
import configuration = require('viewmodels/configure')

class CalendarService implements ICalendarService {
    private NumberOfDaysToSync : number;

    constructor() {
    }

    getCalendarNames(): string[] {            
        return ["My Calendar","My Other Calendar"];
    }

    pullLatestSchedule(calendarName : string) {

    }
}

export = CalendarService;
```

I could get rid of the error, but then I would be introducing logical error, which's even worse, because then it'd be an application bug.

eg. replace the following line: `calendarService = calendarServiceImport;` with `calendarService = new calendarServiceImport();` but makes no sense as I would be instantiating the object a 2nd time.

How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TypeScript and Durandal disagree about the semantics of `require` ("import this" vs "import a new instance of this"), you'll need to add a cast somewhere.

Option 1 -- cast at the consumption site:

```
import calendarServiceImport = require("service/CalendarService");

var calendarService = <ICalendarService><any>calendarServiceImport;
```

Option 2 -- cast at the export site:

```
import configuration = require('viewmodels/configure')

class CalendarService implements ICalendarService {
    private NumberOfDaysToSync : number;

    constructor() {
    }

    getCalendarNames(): string[] {            
        return ["My Calendar","My Other Calendar"];
    }

    pullLatestSchedule(calendarName : string) {

    }
}

var instance = <ICalendarService><any>CalendarService;    
export = instance;
```

Comment: You sir, are awesome! TYVM!!! I picked the later solution, always consolidate complexity at the production site. - more cohesion.